# Calculating inductance of solenoid using a resonant RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks, inductance, resonance

I tried to perform an experiment in my school physics lab with an RLC circuit. I plotted the variation of the voltage across the resistor against the frequency of the source.

From the figure below, it can be seen that resonance is obtained at 828Hz, but on calculating the inductance of my inductor (homemade) using the resonance frequency equation, I got 7.9mH. This is greater than the inductance of the solenoid calculated using inductance of a solenoid equation. Could someone please help me understand why?

**Calculations**
[image: Calculations]

[image]

[image: My home-made solenoid]

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: How did you make the inductor? Picture of the schematic used, means of measurement.

Comment: What's the value of the capacitor?  Is your voltmeter really rated for use at the frequencies you are using?

Comment: Show your calculation of the inductance using the solenoid equation (include the values used.) Show your calculation of the inductance using the resonance frequency (include the values used.)

Comment: The capacitor was rate 4.7 microfarad.

Comment: I have edited my post to show my calculations

Comment: What is "G"? What voltmeter did you use? You may need to use an oscilloscope instead. Also, I assume the unit 'F' in the derivation is just a typo (inductance in 'H').